# finiteness of the homology of an augmented Koszul complex

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(A,m)$ be a local ring $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ elements of $m$ and $M$ a finite $A$-module. Let $K(x)$ be the Koszul complex associated with $x_1,\cdots,x_n$. We define a new complex by $K(x) \otimes M$. Let $H_p(x,M)$ be the homology at dimension $p$ of $K(x) \otimes M$.

> Question: Why is it true that $H_p(x,M)$ is a finite $A$-module?

Remark: This shows up in the proof of the theorem that if $H_1(x,M)=0$ then the sequence $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ is $M$-regular. See for example Lang (Algebra) p. 856, Matsumura (CRT) p. 129.

Comment: Assuming you are assuming the ring is noetherian, this follows immediately from noetherianness! (If you are not assuming that, then it is not true) (This suggests the question is not really on-topic here and should have been asked, say, on math.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Well, i am reading Lang's and Matsumura's text and they don't say anything about Noetherianity.

Comment: Let $A$ be the quotient of a polynomial ring in infinitely many variables by the ideal generated by all monomials of degree $2$, let $n=1$, let $x_1\in A$ be one of the variables, and let $M=A$. Compute $H_1(x,M)$.

Comment: Awesome! So, i wonder then why it is that both Lang and Matsumura do not mention this assumption. I would have expected it from Matsumura since he is very precise in his statements. Anyway, i can accept your answer if you write it.

Comment: Many people incorporate noetheriannity into the definition of «local ring».

Comment: But neither Matsumura nor Lang defines a local ring to be noetherian.

Comment: @FredRohrer: Exactly. And as i pointed out, it would be in Matsumura's style to mention it. What a mystery.